# "Под дых" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Часто сталкивают с этим оборотом. Подскажите, пожалуйста, слитно или раздельно пишется "ударить под дых". С одной стороны, это устоявшееся выражение, а с другой - Ворд постоянно его подчеркивает.
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В русском языке существует целый ряд наречий, которые не употребляются без предлога, но пишутся раздельно. Для данной группы слов факт наличия падежного управления  (и фактически ПРЕДМЕТНОГО ЗНАЧЕНИЯ) имеет преимущественное  значение: до зарезу, до упаду, без прОсыпа, без ведома, без продыху, на дыбы, на попятную, на побегушках, на убой,   с лихвой, с ведома,  во всеуслышание, во всеоружии,  по старинке, не по нутру.

Также:без умолку, без устали, без удержу,  без обиняков, без оглядки (в этом случае раздельное написание дополнительно связано с тем, что предлог заканчивается на согласную, а слово начинается на гласную)

Соответственно, "под дых" пишется раздельно (ударить под дых - это ударить (подо что?) под дыхательный центр, управление В. падежом, направленное пространственное значение.

Answer (score 2):

А что Ворд пишет при этом? Может, просто указывает что "дых" слово разговорное, едва ли не просторечное.
Слитное написание (поддых) никаким современными словарями не допускается.